# Is a tilted, no lens telescope, can work?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, telescopes

I got a crazy idea to build a no-lense telescope with an optical zoom of 100,000. Please tell me where it will fail :)

- Go into a dark room
- Make a 0.1-millimeter hole in the ceiling
- Take a 10-meter square board covered with 1,000,000 light sensors
- put it under the center of the hole, with a tiny angle such that the top of the board is 0.1-millimeter farther from its bottom

I assume that the skylight from the 0.1-millimeter hole will cover the entire 10 meters board, and the light sensors will be able to capture a 1,000,000 pixels picture.

[image]

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_obscura for a historical use of the device. Link to a page with more history of the theory of optimal hole size https://www.pinhole.cz/en/pinholecameras/pinhole_01.html . Not sure I get why the idea of a tilted image plane is supposed to help. It would, at most, work in one dimension, unless you are planning on a series of holes? It certainly doesn't improve the diffraction limited resolution.

Comment: the tilted plane gives a larger surface area for catching the light, thus the 1,000,000 pixels resolution :)

Comment: @James A pinhole camera with small holes is diffraction limited. Using a small hole size is therefor a bad idea. Handwavingly the diffraction limited resolution of a pinhole camera is the same as that of a conventional lens or mirror camera/telescope of equivalent diameter, except the that pixel size for large pinholes approximates the size of the "pinhole". So if we are using a 10cm size pinhole to approximate a small telescope, then our pixels will be 10cm in size and we would have an "optimal" image plane the size of a football field, or so.

Comment: your drawing is not accurate according to pin-hole camera optics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera#Usage . See this article to get an idea of what will happen to the image without a lense https://astronomyteacher.org/2020/01/15/the-pinhole-camera-and-the-telescope/ ,  This means that in order for the sky image to be formed enlarged looking through your pinhole telescope, you would have to wait a very long time, to have an image on film, and the earth will move and blur it in the meantime to nonsence

Comment: this quote from the link makes it clear on how telescopes work, " “every point on the lens receives the entire image”." The lens is an instrument to add the photons from all points hitting the lens so that there is enough intensity  to register in the  small  time interval that the eye sees the image

Comment: @annav suppose the "sky" is a just static projection picture, then this setup will work as an optical photo magnifier to any arbitrary large size, as long as we are patient enough to expose the film for a long time?

Comment: @James yes, and enough distance to see the magnification that the telescope gives in the experiment in the link.

Comment: @James note that I am using light sensors. They give you a boolean answer if they are hit by light or not. Out of 1,000,000 sensors, a picture is forming. Today we have devices with much bigger sensitivity than the human eye, it might even be possible to capture a single photon.

Comment: @IlyaGazman yes, do let me know if you have an image result!

Comment: Re, "it might even be possible to capture a single photon." Astronomers already are using detectors that can do that, but a single detection event is not a signal. In fact, a single event is indistinguishable from noise, which is present in any system. Besides the "diffraction limit" to which other comments here allude, another reason why astronomers build telescopes with huge apertures is to collect _enough_ photons to be able to learn things about extremely faint astronomical objetcts.